# Why is postgres not re-using sub-query results when having a query of the shape `A UNION A`?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

Say we have the following Postgres DB schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  birthdate date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (id, name, birthdate) VALUES
(1, 'Joe', '2018-01-01'),
(2, 'Robert', '2017-01-02'),
(3, 'Mike', '1997-03-01');
```

And we run a query like this:

```sql
(SELECT * FROM users) UNION (SELECT * FROM users)
```

[Link to SQLfiddle with this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b215/34)

then the `EXPLAIN` results we get are [as follows](https://explain.depesz.com/s/3mZy):

```
                    HashAggregate  (cost=86.00..110.00 rows=2400 width=40)
                      Group Key: users.id, users.name, users.birthdate
                      ->  Append  (cost=0.00..68.00 rows=2400 width=40)
                            ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40)
                            ->  Seq Scan on users users_1  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40)
```

It seems like Postgres is doing two sequential scans over the `users` table, appending the results, and discarding duplicates.

Is there a reason why Postgres does not realize that this query could be simplified to `SELECT * FROM users`?

---

The given example here is of course super-simple, and if queries like these are hand-written we can realize that we might be able to optimize them. But in the actual project I'm working on, we have queries that are generated from a buch of 'rules' objects: Some of the sub-queries in a rule are time-dependent (A: 'did user join less than X days ago'), but many are not (B: 'is the user female').

When combining these rules to see e.g. results for the last three days, we have something like `(A UNION B) UNION (A' UNION B) UNION (A'' UNION B)` which could be simplified to `A UNION A' UNION A''' UNION B`, but currently it does not seem that Postgres is doing this.

And related, many of these subqueries perform the same kind of INNER JOINs with other tables, but it seems that all of those tables are re-iterated in each of the subqueries as well.

Is it something that can be enforced by adding the correct indices, adding some hints to the queries or something else, or is it just an optimization that Postgres currently does not do during query planning?

Comment: I'd say it's an optimization that is simply not available (and a strange case to begin with in my eyes, so I'm not surprised that this isn't detected, especially if the real query is much more complicated)

Comment: It's not a common case to begin with. I would be surprised if the PostgreSQL team paid any attention to border cases like this one. If you have a real life issue like this one, I would place the inner query in a CTE and would perform the UNION in the outer query. You would get the optimization you want that way.